# Why should you start with Substrate?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, evm, blockchain

Why should you start with Substrate?

Comment: Substrate is exactly as its name suggests, is a solid foundation, like a planned land and converges the essential conditions to build a blockchain in the most optimal direction, fixing all defects. Etherium points...

Answer (score 2):

Substrate allows you to handle the complex processes of Blockchain development without the limitations imposed by other frameworks. Since its launch, Substrate has been shaped to be a flexible and highly customizable modular framework.

This platform helps developers quickly build Blockchain with well-researched code. After much experimentation, Substrate's modules have proven their worth on billions of dollars worth of live networks.

If you're a beginner developer, you won't have to start from scratch with the Substrate system. You can take advantage of the open source software built by Substrate's large ecosystem to get off to a great start.
This ecosystem includes the world's leading Blockchain development projects. And of course, they're completely free. Like the beginner apps, the Blockchains from Substrate are also
some outstanding functions of Substrate:
Persistent storage, support functions, Unlimited upgrades, safety and speed, custom messages...

[image]

Comment: Why did you add that picture?

Comment: Yeah, although this picture would help to explain the relation of validators, it is not introduced properly in the text.